# redirect specific sub domain on specific folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I have one sub domain  `api.example.com`.

my code is on `/var/www/html/` folder.

my all sub domain is redirect to `/var/www/html` folder.

but i want `api.example.com` to redirect on `/var/www/html/api` folder. how it is possible?

I have do some RND but not find any answer related to this.

Right now i am use a `DNS` for redirection. like this.

`*.example.com. 14400   IN  A   52.46.171.238`.

It is possible using `.htaccess` or i have to do something with `DNS records`?.

Comment: Please show us your current redirect code that redirects all your subdomains. Where is this redirected located?

Comment: @MrWhite, currently my redirection rule is in DNS. like this. `*.example.com. 14400 IN A 52.46.171.238`

Comment: DNS is not a "redirect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over Apache server config then it is easier to do it in `VirtualHost` by using appropriate `DocumentRoot`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api
    ,,,
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

However if you don't have control over Apache server config then do it using a rewrite rule in `/var/www/html/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^api/ api%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: when i use this writing in apache2 conf file then it is not working. i have try to add it in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file. And after that i restart the apache but it is not working

Comment: I also try using create one another `conf` file and put this code on that file in same above folder but it is not working.

Comment: check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600547/rewrite-rules-in-apache-config-is-not-working

Comment: this is work for `api.example.com` but when i try to open `api.example.com/v1` v1 is folder inside api folder, then it is giving me a `404 page not found error`.

Comment: @anubhava , this solution is also changing the url. check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709724/url-redirection-working-incorrect-using-htacess-in-php , it is possible without changing URL