# url redirection working incorrect using .htacess in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have one sub domain  api.example.com.

my code is on `/var/www/html/` folder.

my all sub domain is redirect to `/var/www/html` folder.

I am use api.example.com to redirect on `/var/www/html/api` folder. Using `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^api/ api%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

But the problem is, it is also change my url , `api.example.com/api` i don't want to change my URL.

when i type `api.example.com` in browser tab and press enter then it is change into the `api.example.com/api` and it is open `index` file of `api folder` but i don't want to change my URL and it will open index file of api folder.

Comment: What does it change the URL to? Is this all your htaccess file contains, or are there other rewrites?

Comment: @CBroe, when i type `api.example.com` in browser tab and press enter then it is change into the `api.example.com/api`

Comment: @anubhava, when i write `api.example.com` then it give me `301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)` and then call `api.example.com/api`.

Comment: I will have to ask again. What happens when you enter `api.example.com/foo1234` in browser?

Comment: 404 page not found error

Comment: ok good, so URL didn't change, which means this rule is not doing a 301 redirect and it is happening somewhere else. Can you test `http://api.example.com/` from a new browser.

Comment: Delete your browser cache before you test a new rewrite rule

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?api(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /api/$1 [L,NC]
```

#### Notice

Delete you  Browser Cache before you test. If this still so not what you want, than you have somwere some other rule in place.